# How to drive external LEDs using Digilent Genesys (Virtex-5) FPGA? How to use pressure or IR sensor input?

Tags: led, fpga, infrared, virtex-series-fpga

How can I drive an FPGA with Digilent Genesys X LEDS with a breadboard and socket 752 DIP?  If the LED of range is zero + 445 and the impedence is 74 what is the range of the flash?  This is for reconfiguring the blocks WITH CLB Verilog and not using a system of linear equations.

Comment: If you want to make the sensors as realistic as possible, they're normally a big (physically large, I mean) inductor. Metal near them changes the inductance (which you can sense as, for one example, a change in impedance at a particular frequency).

Comment: You should really roll this back. The question now has nothing to do with the accepted answer.

Comment: Rolled back to the version, which was current at the time when the accepted answer was accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wow, using a Virtex-5 for this is massive overkill - on the scale of using a nuke to open a peanut.

I'm not sure what voltage the I/O on the Genesys board runs at; as long as it's 3.3V (and it probably is) you should be able to connect a LED of any colour via a series resistor (higher or lower value for lower or higher brightness, start with 1kohm) to ground using one of the PMOD ports.  Turn the LED on by putting a '1' on the output, or off with any other value.  Take a look at Digilent's [LED PMOD](http://www.digilentinc.com/Products/Detail.cfm?NavPath=2,401,511&Prod=PMOD-LED) for a schematic, and also their [BTN PMOD](http://www.digilentinc.com/Products/Detail.cfm?NavPath=2,401,507&Prod=PMOD-BTN).

External sensors are going to be, well, buttons - unless you're trying to detect the presence of vehicles, which could get a bit more complicated.  If you are, then something along the lines of a small magnet in each vehicle and a hall-effect switch underneath the model road would do nicely.  The outputs of hall-effect switches behave like a switch or button, so they're convenient to work with; they typically provide an open-collector output that pulls to ground in the presence of a (strong enough) magnetic field.

Comment: You can use a reed switch with a magnet attached to a toy car.